# In App Purchase : adding new items for sale

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I Just wanna make sure if I got it right,
If I want to sell ebooks through my iphone app, I shouldn't bundle them with my application ( because I want to add ebooks for sale from time to time ), they should be put on a separate server, and each time i want to add an ebook, I add its information in itune connect , and the ebook itself is put on a server to be downloaded when purchased, is this correct ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct, however every in-app items will be also review by Apple.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any tutorial or sample app to implement this IAP?